# Search through a folder to move an uploaded file to a subfolder - Google forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-forms

I have a google form that collects details of a set of individuals. They select several options and finally upload a file. I want these files to be uploaded to a specific folder (based on form selection options) that is already created in the google drive. I have found a very good answer in the forum, however, the search of the subfolder (not there is the below reference) is a bit cloudy to me.

Reference:
[How to Move File Uploads from Google Forms to a Specific Folder & Subfolders in Google Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66436387/how-to-move-file-uploads-from-google-forms-to-a-specific-folder-subfolders-in/66456505#66456505?newreg=d619ac9e5f514c3eaa6a94a7e8ea2f93)

Example: A person fills the form Q1. "1", Q2. "form 1" <- the upload. My other options for Q1 are 2 and 3. Inside my custom "reports" folder (in goolge drive) I have placed the 1,2 and 3 folders. I want this particular upload to end up in the "1" folder. With the below code, the file gets uploaded to some other folder, i.e., Form uploads.

```
const PARENT_FOLDER_ID = "<folder ID>";

const initialize = () => {
  const form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("onFormSubmit").forForm(form).onFormSubmit().create();
};

const onFormSubmit = ({ response } = {}) => {
  try {
    // Get some useful data to create the subfolder name
    const answer = response.getItemResponses()[0].getResponse() // text in first answer
  
    // Get a list of all files uploaded with the response
    const files = response
      .getItemResponses()
      // We are only interested in File Upload type of questions
      .filter(
        (itemResponse) =>
          itemResponse.getItem().getType().toString() === "FILE_UPLOAD"
      )
      .map((itemResponse) => itemResponse.getResponse())
      // The response includes the file ids in an array that we can flatten
      .reduce((a, b) => [...a, ...b], []);

    if (files.length > 0) {
      // Each form response has a unique Id
      const parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(PARENT_FOLDER_ID);
      const subfolder = parentFolder.getFoldersByName(answer).next(); //I am stuck at this point, how can I search for the particular folder and push the file inside
      files.forEach((fileId) => {
        // Move each file into the custom folder
        DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).moveTo(subfolder);
      });
    }
  } catch (f) {
    Logger.log(f);
  }
};
```

Comment: Hi. I'm not clear about exactly what is your question. Do you want to create/edit a script so that for all **future** form submissions, uploaded files are saved to the appropriate folder; OR do want to want a script that will search through an **existing**  folder and move **existing** files to appropriate folders.

Comment: FYI, the script that you have included in your question is from the referenced _question_ **NOT the answer**. You said that the search is `is a bit cloudy to me.` What do you mean by `a bit cloudy` and which _specific_ part of the script is your problem?

Comment: @Tedinoz, thank you for your reply. The folders are already existing. I want a new submission (with an upload) to end up in the already existing folder. The folder selections will be in the Google form. I have indicated the confused part in the code (it is in the IF statement in the code. I have modified it a bit. But I am not very sure on how to do it, hence a bit cloudy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a Google Form that accepts file uploads. You intend that the answer to Q#1 on the form will dictate the upload folder for the user file. You have created folders "1, "2","3" on Google Drive to hold uploads.

- a user who answers 1, should have their file upload put in a folder name = "1"
- a user who answers 2, should have their file upload put in a folder name = "2"
- a user who answers 3, should have their file upload put in a folder name = "3"

The solution to this problem is a spreadsheet linked to the Google form and which accepts responses from Form submissions. The spreadsheet will run a script when each form submission is received; the script will move the file upload to the appropriate folder.

---

**Installation:**

- These script are bound to the spreadsheet.
- Copy ALL the code shown below and paste into the project editor
- find this line `const subfolderIDs = ["<<folderID_1>>","<<folderID_2>>","<<folderID_3>>"]`

  - substitute the folderId for each of folders "1", "2" and "3".
- Manually run `createSpreadsheetOnFormSubmitTrigger()`

  - do this once (and only once).
  - This will programmatically create the `onFormSubmit` trigger

---

```
// create a trigger that will fire when the spreadsheet has a form submitted to it.
function createSpreadsheetOnFormSubmitTrigger(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("moveFileSubmission")
    .forSpreadsheet(ss)
    .onFormSubmit()
    .create();
}

function moveFileSubmission(e){
  // these are the sub-folders in the UPLOAD FOLDER that relate to the answers to Q1
  const subfolderIDs = ["1S0x9KcR1VgD00Op_G_lV9EnGwRmMuL2P","1VWae65JeDNbXgraIloPh-h9q2CVLXvD4","1m7CcLYcaGOtH_ojMR2RKEWqxEzt7L0Qi"]

  // get Event Objects and values 
  var response = e.values;
  // answer to Question 1
  var question1 = response[1]
  // the file url of the upload
  var fileUrl = response[2]

  // get the fileId from the fileUrl
  var fileId = getIdFromUrl(fileUrl)
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: question#1 answer = "+question1+", URL = "+fileUrl+", fileID = "+fileId)

  // get the subfolderID based on the answer to qn#1
  var subfolderID = subfolderIDs[(question1-1)]
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the subfolder id = "+subfolderID)

  // get the subfolder
  var subfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(subfolderID)

  // Move the uploaded file into the appropriate folder
  DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).moveTo(subfolder)
}


//Easiest way to get file ID from URL on Google Apps Script
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/16840612/1330560
function getIdFromUrl(url) { 
  return url.match(/[-\w]{25,}/); 
}
```

---

**LOGIC**

- `const subfolderIDs` - the target folderIds are in an array (zero-based). This makes it easy to take the answer to question#1 and select the appropriate folderId.
- `var response = e.values;`- the solution makes use of [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)
- `var question1 = response[1]` & `var subfolderID = subfolderIDs[(question1-1)]`

  - get answer to question#1,
  - subtract 1 (for the zero-based array),
  - get that value from the array of subfolderIDs.
- `var fileUrl = response[2]` - the url of the uploaded file is included in the Event Objects BUT there's currently no way to get a file by URL. So we need to use a utility `getIdFromUrl()` to extract the FileID from the URL.
- `var subfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(subfolderID)` - gets the destination folder.
- `DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).moveTo(subfolder)` - moves the file to the appropriate folder.

---

**Comments on the OP's referenced script**

The OP included a script from [How to Move File Uploads from Google Forms to a Specific Folder & Subfolders in Google Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66456505/1330560). Though it appeared similar to the OP's scenario, it was actually quite different.

- involved multiple uploads per user
- required a unique upload folder for EVERY user.
- got file details via the form rather than the spreadsheet.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed solution. When you say paste into the project editor, you mean form's script editor? or sheet's script editor?

Comment: All uploads are still getting uploaded to the upload folder associated with the google form. :(

Comment: All scripts are bound to the spreadsheet script Editor.  When the form is submitted, any files will be uploaded to the folders automatically created when the relevant question was created. When the submission response is detected in the spreadsheet, any files will be then moved to the appropriate folder.